# Excel Copy Dynamic Cell Value

Tags: vba

I've a very simple VBA function to copy the value of a cell(which is the summation of a range) to an empty cell. The program loops 50 times, the L53 cell contains the summation of a Range that changes each time as the NORMINV(RAND(),0,1) generates different values per loop.

```
Sub Run_Calc_Btn_Click()
For i = 1 To 50
Range("O" & i + 1).Value = Range("L53")
Next i
End Sub
```

However, the copied value does not equal to the original cell value and I couldn't figure out where does this value come from.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your function and I think that the problem is that after the last loop the value changes again.

If you as a quick debug add the following as the first line inside the for loop: `MsgBox "Value of L53: " & Range("L53").Value`, you will see that each cell in column O does indeed match the sum in cell L53.

Before you click OK in the messagebox, you can verify that the value in cell L53 is the same as the value shown in the messagebox and after you click OK the next cell in column O will have the value that was just shown in the messagebox.